# jQuery Draggable and negative css left

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm working with jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable:
Here is the situation:
1. We have a div, with "widgets" ( Like widgets on android phone ).
2. We have a second div, where the widgets are supposed to be dropped.

To problem is, that the second div ( Where we can drop widgets from 1st div ) can have a negative css left value ( It's because there is a carousel on the second div ). And when I'm trying to drop something on the second div when it has f.e. left = -200px, the helper is positioned 200px from the cursor. Where the left value is bigger, the helper can be outside the screen. ). Any advices?

Comment: It will be useful to see your code.

Comment: Here goes sample code: jsfiddle.net/EpFdA/3 Try to drag blue divs to grey.

Comment: Can you remove `appendTo:` and `containment:` from your jQuery UI object? This solves the issue of the helper going off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
$('#drawer .tile').draggable({
    appendTo: '#tiles-container',
    zIndex: 10000
});

$('.socket').droppable({
    accept: '.tile',
    drop: function(){
        alert('dropped!');
    }
});
```

When you set the `containment:'#tiles-container'` the draggable helper inherits the left offset.

Comment: It's working, thanks. As a workaround to the containment i had to set is as an array [x1,y1,x2,y2]